# Is this IRF9640 MOSFET operating within the recommended temperature as specified by the datasheet and why is it so hot?

Tags: mosfet, thermal

There's a handful of questions already asked about the differences between operating temperature and ambient temperature for electronic devices, but my question is specifically for the [irf9640](https://www.vishay.com/docs/91086/irf9640.pdf) MOSFET and my application. I am PWM-ing a 0.85 A current through a coil with a D.C. of 20% and a period of 500 us at 12 V making the power dissipated approximately 10W. The [heatsink](https://www.mouser.co.uk/ProductDetail/Aavid/6400BG?qs=U7T%2FEnMyvTuNOzrGxi%252BoFg%3D%3D) that I'm using states 2.7 C/W so I would expect the temperature of the MOSFET to be ambient + 27 C or approx. 52 C if ambient is 25 C. However using a thermal imaging camera I can see that the case temperature of the MOSFET is over 100 C and the heatsink is approximately 70 C.

The MOSFET and heatsink I'm looking at:
[image]

The maximum case temperature of the MOSFET:
[image]

The heatsink temperature is fairly uniform everywhere:
[image]

So my questions:

1. Is the MOSFET operating within an acceptable temperature if I want it to be suitable for an ambient environment of up to 50C (currently 25C environment)?
2. Why is the MOSFET so hot in the first place, are my calculations incorrect, or is it expected behaviour?

Thanks for any advice
edit:
as requested, VGS:
[image]

and VDS:
[image]

and schematic, J9 has the coil across it:
[image]

Comment: 1. Nope. 2. Show your schematic. Show oscillograms of Vgs and Vds. _”making the power dissipated approx. 10 W.”_ Nope. 0.2 x 0.85^2 x 0.5 << 10 W. Something is wrong here.

Comment: Assuming the mosfet is driven correctly, it should be cool as a cucumber. Why the 1R resistor on the source?

Comment: Please show us your _actual_ schematic.

Comment: @Kartman, it won't ever be cool becuase it's energising a coil and getting hot due to the back-emf generated across it. This is for a metal detector. Further pictures added to illustrate.

Comment: What about free wheeling diodes to protect the mosfet against back-emf from the coil?

Comment: @Uwe free-wheeling diode can't be used for this circuit as the back-emf is actually required to be measured. It induces back-emf in a second coil and that is what determines whether metal is present in this type of metal detector. So heat is expected for this design, i just wasn't expecting so much.

Comment: Looks like the coil is pulling up to 4A based on what looks to be an 8V sag over 0.5R Rdson of the mosfet. If we guess at around 2W average over the on time then divide that by 5, that gives us around 0.4W. Still doesn't explain the temperature rise

Comment: _"I am PWM-ing a 0.85 A current through a coil" - Is this average or peak current, and how do you know it's 0.85A? What is the DC resistance and inductance of the coil? What is the peak back-emf voltage across the coil?

Comment: @Bruce Abbott this is average current calculated from (12V / (1R + 1.5R + 0.3R)) * 20%. 1R is the series resistor, 1.5R is rds(on), 0.3R is the coil and multiplying by 1/5 because that's how long on average it's actually conducting for. Peak back-EMF is 250V.

Comment: you haven't taken into account the effect of the inductance. We can see this in the sag in your waveform. What's the voltage rating of the mosfet? I have it as 200V and you're putting 250 across it.

Comment: @Kartman the device is repetetive avalanche rated so I didn't think it mattered. Either way, that still wouldn't help with the heating issue would it? I could increase the series 1R to 2R to halve the current and therefore the back-EMF...

Comment: How much airflow do you have? That heatsink doesn't seem to even have an ambient rating, the 2.7 K/W figure is at about 300 FPM airflow; are you anywhere near that? You have other problems, but without a fan you're still not going to get the 2.7 K/W.

Comment: It appears t me that the gate is not properly driven, probably low voltage and slow rise/fall times. That will definitely cause it to get hot. Only way to know is to see the waveform from source to gate.

Comment: @Hearth this is just with "ambient" airflow, there is no active cooling with a fan and there can't be unfortunately. This item will be installed in a sealed metal enclosure in coal processing plants that get extremely dirty.

Comment: @ChrisD91 You should probably use a heatsink that has an ambient rating, then. This one is only designed to be used with airflow, and there's no rating for its performance with just natural convection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am PWM-ing a 0.85 A current through a coil with a D.C. of 20% and a
> period of 500 us at 12 V making the power dissipated approx. 10 W.

I simulated your circuit in [LTspice](https://www.analog.com/en/design-center/design-tools-and-calculators/ltspice-simulator.html), adjusting R<sub>DSon</sub> to match your waveform. Total FET dissipation was 8 W, consisting of 5.2 W from Drain-Source resistance and 2.8 W of avalanche power. Coil current was 0.85 A average, 2.0 A rms, and 6.3 A peak.

> using a thermal imaging camera I can see that the case temperature of
> the MOSFET is over 100 C and the heatsink is approximately 70 C.

This indicates that the die temperature is well over 100 °C, so R<sub>DSon</sub> is much higher than at 25 °C.

> I would expect the
> temperature of the MOSFET to be ambient + 27 C or approx. 52 C if
> ambient is 25 C.

From the thermal imaging we see that the 'case' (heat sink tab) temperature is only a little higher than the heat sink itself, as expected. The temperature on the top of the FET is closer to the die temperature, which is also expected.

Your heat sink is operating at reduced efficiency because the PCB blocks airflow through the bottom of the fins. You should drill some holes through the PCB between the heat sink fins, and perhaps add a fan to blow air through the fins.

> Is the MOSFET operating within an acceptable temperature if I want it
> to be suitable for an ambient environment of up to 50C (currently 25C
> environment)?

Seems to be OK at 25 °C, but marginal at 50 °C. Improving heat sinking and/or lowering MOSFET losses would help keep the temperature down.

> Why is the MOSFET so hot in the first place, are my calculations
> incorrect, or is it expected behaviour?

It is expected behavior. RMS current is high, which heats up the FET causing  R<sub>DSon</sub> to increase which heats it up even more. The FET also has to absorb the flyback energy which heats it up even more.

To prevent avalanching, add a [snubber](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snubber) to get peak back-emf voltage below the FETs rating. This alone may be enough to get the temperature down. If not then use a FET with lower R<sub>DSon</sub>, and/or shorten the pulse to reduce peak current.

You might also consider putting more turns on the coil to get the magnetic field you need at lower current. Ideally the FET should have minimal voltage drop at peak coil current.

Comment: Wow, thanks for the very detailed answer! Unfortunately I want as much back-emf as possible so reducing the "pulse-width" and adding a snubber are the last resorts as this affects the sensitivity of the metal detector. I also can't use passive cooling due to the dirty environment these will be installed in (heavy industry). I'll investigate MOSFETs with lower RDSon but won't the increased gate capacitance cause an issue?

Comment: _"I want as much back-emf as **possible**"_ - I suspected this. The maximum possible back-emf is dependent on coil capacitance and magnetic losses. It is probably much higher than the FET's avalanche voltage. A well tuned RCD snubber would keep voltage below the FET's avalanche voltage without significantly reducing back-emf. Need more? Then use a FET with higher voltage rating. Being 'repetetive avalanche rated' does NOT mean the FET should be operated in this mode continuously...

Comment: https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-ApplicationNote_Some_key_facts_about_avalanche-AN-v01_00-EN.pdf?fileId=5546d462584d1d4a0158ba0210977cde "so as to significantly reduce the impact of repetitive avalanche on technology parameters, Infineon would need to compromise significantly on other figures of merit that are dominant in the vast majority of applications. This would be too high of a price to pay for an event that does not correspond to a normal usage of a MOSFET, and that a designer should **strive to avoid by all means**".

Comment: _"won't the increased gate capacitance cause an issue?"_ - if gate voltage doesn't drop fast enough then reduce the value of R8.

Comment: It looks like my simplest option is to try and find a FET with lower RDS(on) and higher voltage rating just to get that temperature down a little. I can always explore an additional snubber solution at a later time but I can't see how that could possibly work with this design - yet. Thanks for the help!